# TFS 2015 bug TF401029: Could not find commit with id

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015

I made a commit and tried to merge the branch in the last sprint, but I did abandon it using TFS UI during the merging process. Please look at the image below:

[image]

After that, I keep on getting the below error on the SDK home page:

[image]

But, when I run this command:

```
git show C3929475ACE562721FB0E8957FB9B0D30BA123C4
```

It shows the last committed/pushed logs and files as well(after the PR got approved).

The problem is, I can't push the latest changes to remote now that throws an error as:

> ! [remote rejected] TFS_200858_Get_Part_3 -> TFS_200858_Get_Part_3 (A parent commit specified in the supplied included commits is invalid.)
> error: failed to push some refs to branch https://some_remote_branch_url

To update the refs with Origin I tried the below git commands, but no luck:

```
git remote prune origin
git gc --prune=now
```

Now the client deliverable and the job both are at stake.

Thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you clone the project again and put in your changes into the fresh clone?

Comment: @LajosArpad If you are suggesting to create a fresh project that's not possibles due to multiple teams and configs (Team city) dependency.

Comment: I did not suggest creating a fresh project. I'm suggesting that you could clone the existing project to have a good copy.

Comment: @LajosArpad I did a fresh clone of the branch as well but no luck. I believe it's bcz the Remote is preserving the stale ref of the last committed id.

Comment: So you have pushed the unwanted commit remotely? You can revert that commit. I would definitely try to avoid pruning the remote.

Comment: The last PR files are expected to be in the remote. But during the push, the TFS messed up something and generated a stale id that's causing the issue. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the @LajosArpad suggestion. I think, we can try to create a new repo in your project and try to clone your local repo to the new repo.